# How to create a base Ext.app.ViewController common to other view controllers?

Tags: javascript, extjs, viewcontroller, extjs6-classic, extjs6.2

I want to create an base ViewController for all other controllers used in an ExtJS app.

**The problem is that ExtJs is looking for the base class in /classic/src/view instead of /app/view....**

Here is an example:
*in /app/view/base/BaseController.js*

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.base.BaseController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

    doStuff: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

*in /app/view/another/AnotherController.js*

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.another.AnotherController', {
    extend: 'myApp.view.base.BaseController',

    onButtonClick: function() {
        doStuff('Button clicked');
    }
});
```

*in /app/classic/src/view/another/Another.js*

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.another.Another', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'another',
    alias: 'view.another',
    id: 'panel_another',

    controller: 'another',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'The Button',
        handler: onButtonClick
    }]
});
```

However when i run the app, ExtJs throws an error saying that /classic/src/view/base/BaseController.js was not found!

What am i doing wrong here?

Thank you for your time, and for your help!

Comment: Have you included "myApp.view.base.BaseController" entry in required section in application.js

Comment: Yes i did, i forgot to mention it, but the the base controller is referenced in application.js requires section!

Comment: Are you running app on build mode or dev mode ?

Comment: At this point, i am still on DEV mode...

Comment: You just try building your app by "sencha app build" command and then check if same error occurs.

Comment: Its working! I simply did what you suggested, i ran the app build command and it started working! I had no idea i had to build the app for the base controller to be recognized... Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah thats great.Should i post this thing as answer so that other people might get help from this instead of reading comments.

Comment: Yes, please do it! I will mark the answer as the correct one! Thank you for your hel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just try building your app by `sencha app build`.It will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, agree above answer.You can also perform *sencha app refresh*.You can try this in DEV mode.Please try this also.